# How to remove all tags from the head section with a same attribute and tag name

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, element, removechild

I am making a JS function, which will change the icon of the document. Now, I know that this sounds simple, but it is not. I am trying to make a Library, so I need a function that can change the default icon to the desired icon and vice versa. It works fine if I try to change the default icon to the desired icon, but if I try to change the icon to the default one(the one with a gray globe), it does not work.

```js
icon = function(dir){
        if(typeof(dir)==="string"){
            var elem = doc.createElement('link');
            elem.rel = "icon";
            elem.href = dir;
            doc.head.append(elem);
        }else if(typeof(dir)==="boolean"&&dir===false){
            var toBeDel = [];
            var currElems = document.querySelectorAll('link');
            var i = 0; var f = 0;
            while(currElems.length>=0){
                if(currElems[i].rel=="icon"){
                    toBeDel.push(currElems[i]);
                    currElems.length--;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            while(toBeDel.length>=0){
                doc.head.removeChild(toBeDel[f]);
                toBeDel.length--;
                f++;
            }
            var elem = doc.createElement('link');
            elem.rel = "icon";
            elem.href = "/default/noimage.png";
            doc.head.append(elem);
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                console.clear();
                var len = efun.logs.length;
                var sen;
                var i = 0;
                while(len>=0){
                    sen = efun.logs[i];
                    efun.gh = sen[0];
                    console.defaultLog(sen[0]);
                    len--;
                    i++;
                }
            },10);
        }
        else{
            efun.cons("Error in icon() function, the parameter you have entered is not a string directory.");
        }
    }
```

Note: `efun` object is the main library object, `efun.cons()` is a shortcut to `console.log()`, `efun.logs` is an array which contains all `console.logs()` done. Note that I called the `console.clear()` function to remove the error which comes when I try to set the default icon since it does not exist. `console.deafultLog()` is a function, which `console.logs()` with it not being pushed into the `efun.logs` array. But the error is that I want to remove all the `<link rel="icon" href="<!---directory here-->"` elements from the head tag. There can be many elements with icons, so I want to remove all of them. For this, I used `document.querySelectorAll()` in an array, and did several while loops. But still, even though a new link element gets appended into the `<head>` tag, the previous ones which I want to remove remains there, so how can I remove all tags with `<link>` tag and `rel="icon"` attribute. Is there any fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have overcomplicated this.

You can delete all existing `<link>` tags with just one line

```
document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="icon"]').forEach(link => link.remove());
```

To revert back to the "globe" icon, you just need to change the url to something that doesnt exist.

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'icon';
link.href = 'https://fake.url.com/';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

If you want to handle errors better, you can use try catch blocks.

Comment: That is not the problem, the problem was the link tags not being removed. This still not works